# How to convert .dat file to raster?

Tags: raster, ascii, binary

I am very new to GIS and I've looked everywhere for a solution but to no avail.

I want to analyze Himawari 8 Gridded Data. I am following the steps to process gridded data, link below.

http://quicklooks.cr.chiba-u.ac.jp/~himawari_movie/rd_gridded.html

After converting count values to spectral reflectances (I am processing Band01, visible), I am left with a file with the extension '.dat'

The tutorial mentioned above further explains how to visualize this using Generic Mapping Tools (GMT) which I have no problem with. I want to explore and analyze the final raster after applying the processing steps in QGIS. But this software does not see '.dat' file extension as a valid input. I have come across tools which convert ASCII to raster.

The .dat file I have is close to 530MB. I opened it in wordpad and it was all gibberish.

How should I proceed? I've been stuck on this subject for couple of days now and am looking for guides or relevant sources.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you use the function read.delim() in R, you can at least load in the file as a table so that you can get a better idea of the contents. Check out this https://www.scribd.com/document/362474377/Reading-Dat-Files-in-R and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664075/import-dat-file-into-r

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking one question per question.  Since you already have an answer for QGIS, I have removed the reference to ArcGIS, to prevent this from being two questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to read the .dat raster in QGIS (3.4.1). Try going Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Raster Layer (1) then click the button next to raster dataset (2) and select Zmap Plus Grid (.dat, .DAT) (3).

[image]

Comment: That might not be the right format, extension is no guarantee of format. Try opening without specifying the format